# File structure incoherent with docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I was trying to dockerize my project, but I have a few problems, notably with the file (or maybe it's not there and you will enlighten me...).
I have a monorepo reactJS/nestJS.

Here is the structure of my project:

```
.
├── package.json
├── tsconfig.json
├── turbo.json
├── Dockerfile.back
├── Dockerfile.front
├── compose.yaml
├── .dockerignore
├── packages/       (Front-back shared custom types)
└── apps
    ├── back
    |   ├── src/
    |   ├── package.json
    |   └── tsconfig.json
    └── front
        ├── src/
        ├── package.json
        └── tsconfig.json
```

And here is my `Dockerfile.back`:

```
FROM node:18.14.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app
RUN yarn global add turbo

FROM base AS PRUNE_STAGE
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN turbo prune --scope back --docker

FROM base AS INSTALL_STAGE
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=PRUNE_STAGE /app/out/json .
COPY --from=PRUNE_STAGE /app/out/yarn.lock .
RUN yarn install:ci

FROM base AS BUILD_STAGE
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=INSTALL_STAGE /app .
COPY --from=PRUNE_STAGE /app/out/full/ .
COPY ./tsconfig.json ./turbo.json ./.eslintrc.json ./
ENV DB_HOST=db
RUN yarn back-build

FROM base AS SERVE_STAGE
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=BUILD_STAGE /app ./build
COPY --from=INSTALL_STAGE /app ./install
COPY --from=PRUNE_STAGE /app ./prune
EXPOSE 8000
ENTRYPOINT [ "tail", "-f", "/dev/null" ]
# CMD ["yarn", "serve"]
```

And my `compose.yaml`:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  back:
    container_name: back
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.back
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - ./apps/back:/app
      - /app/node_modules/
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    container_name: db
    image: mongo:6.0.6
    volumes:
      - data:/data/db
    restart: always
    expose:
      - 27017

volumes:
  data:
```

(I was just trying to debug the back for the moment)

As you can see from the dockerfile, I just wanted to see where are located the files in all the stages, so I can debug, each in the folder corresponding to it.
However, this is what I get when I execute bash into the container:

```bash
thibault@Mon-PC-U website% docker exec -it 5d /bin/bash                               [Docker]
root@5d62397fcce3:/app# ls -a
.     .env.template  dist           package.json         tsconfig.json
..    .eslintrc.js   nest-cli.json  src
.env  .gitignore     node_modules   tsconfig.build.json
```

And even tried to see if it was somehow somewhere else, but no:

```bash
root@5d62397fcce3:/app# cd ..
root@5d62397fcce3:/# ls -a
.   .dockerenv  bin   dev  home  lib64  mnt  proc  run   srv  tmp  var
..  app         boot  etc  lib   media  opt  root  sbin  sys  usr
```

And now I'm really lost... Any help is welcome

Comment: When you do a volume mapping in your compose file like this `./apps/back:/app`, you tell Docker to hide everything in the image in `/app` and replace it with the `./apps/back` directory on the host.

Comment: Oh god... F me. Indeed, I used this in another project and as I am new at docker and am testing new things, I did it here too, but with such a Dockerfile it's not compatible... Thanks, it should already make a big change!